# How to make a ScrollBar visible on a chart in Visual Basic forms

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2010, charts

I have a chart that needs a ScrollBar. Funny thing is that the ScrollBar is there, but its not visible. I can interact with it on the bottom of the chart and it functions OK. It just isn't visible. Anyhow here is some code...

```
'ch is the Chart
    With ch.ChartAreas(0)
        With .AxisX
            .Minimum = chartMin
            .Maximum = chartMax
            .Interval = 1
            .ScaleView.Size = chartRows
            .ScaleView.Position = chartMax
            With .ScrollBar
                .Size = 20
                .ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll
                .IsPositionedInside = True
                .Enabled = True
                .BackColor = Color.LightGray
                .ButtonColor = Color.Gray
            End With
        End With
        .RecalculateAxesScale()
    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code not shown the x Axes was disabled.
Still doesn't explain why I could interact with an invisible scroll bar but its working now.

Comment: The chart has to have enough data so that the data set is larger then the chart.